# get sum and add incentive in it - mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Please help me with this query.

I have multiple tables as below. I am using **Codeigniter** and **MySQL**.

**franchise**
[image]

**purchase**
[image]

**district**

[image]

**disctrict_owner**
[image]

**region**

[image]

**regional_owner**
[image]

**CASE**

We have Franchise, District Owner, Regional Owner, State Owner.

State Owner has all the Regional Owner under him. Regional Owner has any 3 District under him and *HE MUST BE THE OWNER OF ONE OF THE DISTRICTS*. District Owner owns all the Franchises in the district.

**WHAT MY CLIENT WANT**

He wants to calculate the previous month's sale of the Regional Owner and add an incentive to it. But here is the catch. As Regional Owner must be the owner of one of the 3 districts he owns, he will get 2% incentive for being District Owner(on Total income of district he owns) and 3% incentive on the rest of 2 districts(on Total income of other 2 districts).

If we get a different amount for the **owned** district and the **remaining two** districts separately, that will also work. We can work at 2% and 3% later.

**EXAMPLE** (Example is just for clarification purpose. No need to read if you understood the tables clearly)

**r_id**- region id

**do_id**- district_owner id

**f_id**- franchise id

If we consider 1st ID in the regional_owner table, his district owner id i.e do_id is 1 and region id i.e r_id is also 1. do_id 1 means we need to check for district_owner table having id 1. If we check so, we can see that district_owner with id 1 is the owner of district 1 and this district come under region 1.

r_id 1 from regional_owner table means region id 1 from region table. region table with id 1 shows that it has 3 districts under district_id i.e 1,2,3.

So, if we need to calculate sale and incentive of regional_owner with id 1, then he will get 2% on the total sale of district 1 which he owns. And 3% on the total sale of the remaining districts i.e 2 & 3.

Please provide the MySQL query for the same. OR suggest me the solution so that I can complete the task.

Thank you

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I added an example and images too. Can you please tell me, what is lacking so I can add?

Comment: I can only refer you again to my previous comment. I'm satisfied that the accepted answer is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you change the column names. when you give `id` as a name for a column in a table its perfectly alright. but giving the column name of `id` for all the tables makes it extremely hard for the developers to work with. sure we can use [Aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) commands but if I were you I'd change the names immediately.

moreover, instead of adding the `district_id` in the region table, I suggest you add `region_id` in the `district table`. this will make it a lot easier in simplifying the joining process.